# Как сравнить ViewBag.Error?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Не могу сравнить @ViewBag.Error из контроллера , так как это не строка(
Как это исправить?

```
<script>
    function Notification() {
        if (@ViewBag.Error != null)
        {
            ...
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Вроде нужно писать @if (ViewBag.Error != null)

Comment: @coder675 так нужно писать в html , а мне надо в скрипте